# How to merge old version to head of a branch in git?

Tags: git

My repository has 2 branches, *master* and *mybranch*. I've commited many times into *mybranch*, realized that many of my changes were not what I wanted.

Thus, I did a `git checkout` of an old commit on* mybranch* using

```
git checkout 02c383
```

I want this old commit to be the `HEAD` of *mybranch*. How do I do this?

When I look at my branches, I see:

```
$ git branch
*(detached from numbershere)
mybranch
master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git checkout mybranch
git reset --hard 02c383
```

After this, `mybranch` will be moved to point to `02c383`.

Comment: Okay, but then I added a file, then did a git add, commit. When I do a git push origin mybranch I got "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart"

Comment: Ah, ok, you had already pushed `mybranch` before. Does anyone else work on the repo, or is it just you? If it is just you (and you must be SURE of this), then do a `git push -f`. Otherwise, I'll edit my answer for another way.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the current branch to a different commit with

```
git reset --hard <ref>
```

In your example, this translates to

```
git reset --hard 02c383
```

Beware that

- you should avoid doing such things (esp. when *mybranch* is already used by others)
- getting back to the previous commit to which *mybranch* pointed before (which is now a [dangling commit](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery) becomes a bit tricky, if you can't remember that SHA.

Comment: I am unable to git push origin mybranch after making a change immediately after doing the reset. I did: git reset, added a file, git commit, git push origin mybranch. Getting " ! [rejected]        mybranch -> mybranch (non-fast-forward)"

Comment: Sure, that's the big red warning sign. You have to use `git push --force` - warnings that you are doing dangerous things (rewriting the history of that branch) apply.